# Overcome SQL MERGE Failure

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to update the customer old values with new values. I need some suggestions in handling the update.

TEMP_TABLE has the below data

| ORDER_ID | CUSTOMER_NAME | OLD_VALUE | NEW_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sam | ABC | DEF |
| 1 | Sam | ABC | GHI |
| 2 | Sam | ABC | DEF |
| 2 | Sam | ABC | GHI |
| 3 | Sam | ABC | DEF |
| 3 | Sam | ABC | GHI |

I am using the below MERGE statement for updating these values into the TARGET_TABLE

```
merge into target_table tt
using (
          select distinct order_id, old_value, new_value
            from test_table 
       )
 test on (test.order_id= tt.order_id)
 when matched then 
 update set tt.old_value= test.new_value;
```

This MERGE statement will fail with unstable set of records, since each ORDER_ID has 2 NEW_VALUEs.

I can use a max(NEW_VALUE) and proceed with the update. But the requirement is as below:

1. For ORDER_ID = 1; the NEW_VALUE can be updated to DEF or GHI
2. For ORDER_ID = 2; the NEW_VALUE shouldn't be same NEW_VALUE as ORDER_ID = 1. If ORDER_ID=1 NEW_VALUE was updated to DEF then ORDER_ID = 2 should get updated with GHI
3. For ORDER_ID = 3; it could be either of the 2 NEW_VALUEs.

Need suggestions on how to handle such scenarios

Comment: Does every `id` have two rows, one `DEF` and one `GHI`?  If not, how would you want to handle a case where you picked `DEF` for `id` 3 and `id` 4 has `DEF` and another value `XYZ`?  Do you pick the one that has the fewest total occurrences?

Comment: For id 4, we will update with value XYZ

Comment: And that is because...?  Is my guess "pick the value that has had the smallest number of previous occurrences" correct?  Or is there some other algorithm (potentially one that involves looking ahead to higher ID values)?

Comment: Pick value that has had smallest occurrence. Goal is to update the OLD_VALUES with all the possible available NEW_VALUES.

Comment: @JustinCave - Any suggestions?